# Implementing custom "cover?"-based method

Tags: ruby, range

How to implement custom method "cover_e?" which implemented almost like standard 
    Range#cover?(val) 
which returns true if obj is between the begin and end of the range.

```
 ("a".."z").cover?("c")    #=> true
```

Custom method should work with "nested"/"inherited" ranges like: ((2..5))

```
(1..10).cover_e?((2..5))   # true 
(5..15).cover_e?((10..20)) # false
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
class Range
  def cover_e? rng
    rng.minmax.all?{|i| self.include? i}
  end
end
p (1..10).cover_e?((2..5))
p (5..15).cover_e?((10..20))
# >> true
# >> false
```

Or

```
class Range
  def cover_e? rng
    (rng.to_a | self.to_a).size == self.size
  end
end
p (1..10).cover_e?((2..5))
p (5..15).cover_e?((10..20))
# >> true
# >> false
```

Comment: All known words of gratitude already used for Priti. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
class Range
  def cover_e? other
    cover?(other.min) and cover?(other.max)
  end
end
```